# The filetype you are attempting to upload is not allowed ods file in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, file-upload, ods

i want to upload an ods file ,but its showing an error:
The filetype you are attempting to upload is not allowed

```
$config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
            $config['allowed_types'] = 'ods|csv|xls';
    //      $config['max_size'] = '';
            $config['max_width']  = '';
            $config['max_height']  = '';
            $this->load->library('upload', $config);

            if (!$this->upload->do_upload())
            {
                $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());

                $this->load->view('uploadstatement',$error);
            }

                    else
            {
    $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
    $data1=$this->upload->data();
    $csv_file1=$data1['file_name'];
```

Answer (score 0):

`added/replaced` the following line to the mime types file `application/config/mimes.php`

```
'xlsx' => array('application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'
```